# Why maximize button get removed when I click or try to maximize window in PyQt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qt5

I've a simple pyqt application in which I've some code for UI which is responsible for realtime speech-to-text in application everything works fine but when I try to maximize my application by clicking on maximize icon it get remove and window does not maximized here is output how it looks

[image]

This is my code.

```py
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setWindowTitle("Speech To Text")
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | Qt.WindowMaximizeButtonHint)
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint)
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint)

        self.app_name = QtWidgets.QLabel("Speech To Text")

        self.hbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.someButton1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("btn1")
        self.someButton2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("btn2")
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.someButton1)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.someButton2)

        self.grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        
        self.topBtn1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Top Button 1")
        self.topBtn2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Top Button 2")
        self.topLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.topLayout.addWidget(self.topBtn1)
        self.topLayout.addWidget(self.topBtn2)

        self.startButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.startLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.startLabel.setText("Tap To Record")
        self.startLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.startLayout.addWidget(self.startButton, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.startLayout.addWidget(self.startLabel, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)        
        self.startLayout.addStretch()

        self.stopButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.stopLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.stopLabel.setText("Stop")
        self.stopLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.stopLayout.addWidget(self.stopButton)
        self.stopLayout.addWidget(self.stopLabel)

        self.vbox.addLayout(self.topLayout)
        self.vbox.addLayout(self.startLayout)
        self.vbox.addLayout(self.stopLayout)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.app_name, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter, stretch=1)
        
        self.editor = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()

        self.grid.addLayout(self.hbox, 0, 2)
        self.grid.addLayout(self.vbox, 1, 1)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.editor, 1, 2)
        self.setLayout(self.grid)
```

I've not provided full code, only main code, and also I'm using Ubuntu, and some methods on the **MainWindow** class update the UI on clicking buttons *(it is just for extra information)*. What's the issue please let me know because on same system another simple application works perfectly.

Comment: Why are you setting those window flags? What happens when those lines are removed?

Comment: Hello @ekhumoro Thanks for replying to my question. About your query: It seems those lines are effectless; if I remove or add them, it does not change anything. I took those lines from some other posts on stackoverflow.

Comment: And on windows system maximize button works(does not get removed on click) only on linux(ubuntu) it does not work.

Comment: The platform window manager controls how those button work. The buttons work fine for me on arch-linux, but I'm using an openbox window manager. What version of ubuntu are you using, and what specific window manager? Also, what specific version of qt5 are you using?

Comment: Hello @ekhumoro, sorry for taking your time. I figured out that the problem was different on Windows and Linux due to differences in spacing. I had added too much margin to the `QVBoxLayout()` elements, causing them to overflow the screen. After reducing the margins and setting `window.showMaximized()`, it now takes up the full screen width and height, and it's working now. Once again, thank you.

Comment: Hello @ekhumoro can you explain me how can I give spacing which will work same for all OS.

Comment: @AnkitTiwari 1. It seems that your problem could only be experienced under a specific circumstance which is not met by your code, meaning that right now your question is not reproducible (so, off topic); 2. every window manager on Linux has its own quirks, so don't expect the same behavior everywhere, and be careful when dealing with window flags; 3. Qt has a default layout spacing and margin, but it depends on the system and how the style is implemented; it's normally better to keep the default values, as it also considers screen DPI.

Comment: Hello @musicamante so is there any standard way or a standard unit to specify margins and spacing so it will work same on diffrent OS? Because after changing margin values it worked for me

Comment: @AnkitTiwari As said, you should stick to the default values.

Comment: Hello, @musicamante, but default is not enough for example to keep 3 buttons in vertical default spacing was too less so I added more values. Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "default value": not adding spacing or keeping the spacing the same across all OS?

Comment: @AnkitTiwari With "default values" I mean the default behavior Qt provides, which is usually follows the OS conventions and should be quite enough to resemble a *native* layout for any OS: this doesn't mean that it's the same on all system, but it's what it *should be* for each OS. I don't know why it's not enough for you, and without more context it's impossible to give you a valid answer. Note that this discussion is now off topic to this post, so I suggest you to create a new post related to this specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the problem was different on Windows and Linux due to differences in spacing. I had added too much margin to the `QVBoxLayout()` elements, causing them to overflow the screen. After reducing the margins and setting `window.showMaximized()`, it now takes up the full screen width and height, and it's working now.

Make sure to test the spacing on different operating systems, such as Windows, Linux, and MacOS. In my case, Windows took a 150-point margin to give me the correct result, but in Linux it overflowed, so I set it to 50-point and it fixed!